# Tool to normalize text source and build original source from normalized one

Tags: java, text, nlp, normalization

Does somebody know a tool/project on Java which can normalize text (and store normalization log) and then build original source text?

Any approach is appreciated.

The problem:
In order to process input data, we need to normalize it.

The process engine receives normalized text and returns matched positions.

After this step, we need to recover original source equivalent by normalized positions.

Example:

```
Source:
Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an ... ütf Wórd èxämplé

Normalized text (approx):
lorem ipsum scripta blandit partiendo, fastidi accumsan euripidis, liber hendrerit utf word example

Engine output:
lorem ipsum scripta begin 0 end 19
euripidis           begin 56 end 65

Original source equivalent:
Lorem ipsum ad his scripta begin 0 end 26
euripidis                  begin 69 end 78
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Such questions are off-topic on SO. If you provide detail specification it *could* be accepted on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Generally speaking, it's probably easier and more reliable to just keep track of the original text itself than to try to record instructions for regenerating it from the normalized text.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to resolve this issue, we've used `Regex`:

```
// Given
Source:
Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an ... ütf Wórd èxämplé

Stopwords:
ad, his, eum, in, an

ASCII text:
Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an ... utf Word example

Normalized text (approx):
lorem ipsum scripta blandit partiendo, fastidi accumsan euripidis, liber hendrerit utf word example

// Then
Engine output:
lorem ipsum scripta begin 0 end 19
euripidis           begin 56 end 65

To take original text from normalized, used Regex
lorem( (ad|his|eum|in|an))* ipsum( (ad|his|eum|in|an))* scripta
euripidis

// Verify

Original source equivalent:
Lorem ipsum ad his scripta begin 0 end 26
euripidis                  begin 69 end 78
```